# Does the name Montaigne have a literal meaning?

Tags: sens, noms-propres, noms-de-famille

Does the name *Montaigne* (as in [Michel de Montaigne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michel_de_Montaigne)) have a literal meaning that could be translated? I could not find *aigne* in French dictionaries so far. I know that there is a village by that name, but does the name also denote a concept that corresponds to a single word?

Answer (score 5):

I am going to give something of a roundabout answer to the question to explain the pronunciation of this name.

*Montaigne* is an older spelling of *montagne*. Although today the pronunciation of the name is almost always [mɔ̃tɛɲ], in his time it was pronounced [mɔ̃taɲ]. The new pronunciation is in fact a spelling pronunciation (as when some people pronounce the *th* in the English word *clothes*).

At one time the sound now spelt *gn* was very often spelt *ign*. For example, *cogner* was *coigner*, *gagner* was *gaigner*. The spelling reform that replaced almost all occurrences of *ign* with *gn* was for some reason not applied to certain words. The word *oignon*, for example, has retained its original spelling, but unlike *Montaigne*, also its original pronunciation [ɔɲɔ̃]. On the other hand, the word *poigne* has undergone the same process as *Montaigne*. It was originally pronounced [pɔɲ], but since the meaning of the *i* in the spelling is no longer understood by French-speakers, most people now pronounce this word [pwaɲ].

Comment: Yours is a competent answer but to a different question.

Comment: The fact that the name is now pronounced with an *e* sound obscures the connection with *montagne*, which is why the OP didn't connect the two. Also, a previous answer seemed to indicate that *Montaigne* came from the word *montagne*, which is false. The details here were included partially to correct the other answer.

Answer (score -1):

like every where, a name gives the quality/the dignity to a man : he is his name ; it cannot be translated. but, if you wish it, you can understand "montaîgne" like a owner of a forest which the fruit is "chataîgnes" or "Fougères" - "mon" means mine and "aîgne" my proptriety.